# Thread-safe data structures with Data.Map operations

Tags: multithreading, haskell, concurrency

I'm looking for thread-safe data structures that have an interface similar to `Data.Map`, i.e., support fast `insert`, `lookup`, `delete` operations. By "thread-safe" I mean that these operations are atomic/linearizable. I know that I could simply use

```
data MyThreadSafeDS k a = MyThreadSafeDS (TVar (Map k a))
```

but benchmarks show that this performs very poorly when multiple threads are trying to do insertions/deletions concurrently. Interestingly, using an `MVar` gives worse results in this context.

**Background:** I've written a [concurrent hash table](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/concurrent-hashtable) and I'm looking for other *thread-safe* data structures to include in my benchmark results. I'm aware of [hashtables](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hashtables), which doesn't seem to be thread-safe.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by this question. `Data.Map` is a purely functional structure, and as such _always_ thread safe, no? Ok, the purely-functional `insert` etc. isn't as fast as a destructive one could be – but that's kind of orthogonal to thread-safety. I guess what you actually mean to ask is, “what's an associative container that's faster than `Data.Map`, but still thread-safe”?

Comment: @leftaroundabout To clarify: what I meant is a data structure that multiple threads can access _and_ observe the results of each other's modifications. Pure data structures are immutable by design and hence there's no way an `insert` by thread A is witnessed by thread B's `lookup` later on, simply because the `insert` results in a new `Data.Map`, while thread B still has the original.